# how to save time from javascript countdown timer value when form is opened?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, countdowntimer

I have an online exam test project with countdown timer. I have start time (when form is opened) and end time(when we click submit button). My problem is, i can't save start time to database. How to solve it?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var hoursleft = 0;
 /*get value from database*/
 var minutesleft = <?php echo $menit->alat_waktu ?>;
 var secondsleft = 0; 
 var finishedtext = "SELESAI";
 var end1;
 if(localStorage.getItem("end1")) 
 {
  end1 = new Date(localStorage.getItem("end1"));
 }
 else 
 {
  end1 = new Date();
  end1.setHours(end1.getHours()+hoursleft);
  end1.setMinutes(end1.getMinutes()+minutesleft);
  end1.setSeconds(end1.getSeconds()+secondsleft);
 }

var counter = function () {
 var now = new Date();
 var datediff = end1 - now;

 diff = new Date(datediff);

 var milliseconds = parseInt((diff%1000)/100)
    var sec = parseInt((diff/1000)%60)
    var mins = parseInt((diff/(1000*60))%60)
    var hours = parseInt((diff/(1000*60*60))%24);
 if(hours < 10) {
  hours = "0" + hours;
 }
 if (mins < 10) {
  mins = "0" + mins;
 }
 if (sec < 10) {
  sec = "0" + sec;
 }     
 if(now >= end1) {     
  clearTimeout(interval);
  localStorage.setItem("end1", null);
  localStorage.removeItem("end1");
  document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = finishedtext;
  
  if(confirm("TIME OUT !!!"))
  clearInterval(counter);
  window.location.href= "http://localhost/psiko";
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
 } else {
  var value = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
/*--------save variable value to db----------*/ 
/*save countdown timer when form is opened*/
 // document.myform.waktu_awal.value = end1;
/*save countdown timer when submit button is clicked*/
  document.myform.waktu_akhir.value = value;
/*------------------------------------------------*/
  localStorage.setItem("end1", end1);
  document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value; 
 }
}

var interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
</script>
```

waktu_awal is start_time and waktu_akhir is end_time

Comment: When you want to save time in database...when you submit the form?

Comment: i want to save time when form is opened as start time and when i submit form as end time

Comment: I've been able to save end time with "document.myform.waktu_akhir.value = value;" but i still confused what variable value as start time to save

Answer (score 0):

I already do this in my script

```
    $waktu_awal = $_POST;
    $waktu_akhir    = $_POST;
    echo "<td> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"waktu_awal\"   value=\"".$waktu_awal."\"></td>";
    echo "<td> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"waktu_akhir\"  value=\"".$waktu_akhir."\"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
/*--------menyimpan nilai variabel ke db----------*/ 
/*save countdown timer when form is open*/
  document.myform.waktu_awal.value = <--- which variable value should I write in here as my start time?
/*save countdown timer when submit*/
  document.myform.waktu_akhir.value = value;
/*------------------------------------------------*/
```